# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock not showing the alert Message

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to this forum.

I am so so stuck with this; what I find odd in the same exam 'save' button I have previously created ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock alerts and it's working Great! I am not sure what's up with this one ? All your help will be appreciated!!

I am trying to show an alert message if 'order items' text box is edited.

````
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

If (txtOrderItem.Text = "") Then
p.OrderItem = Nothing
Else


 'Dim pp As Page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
  'Dim s = "Notification : Your Message."
  'ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(pp, pp.GetType(), "Notify", "alert('" & s & "');", True)


    'ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "Message100", "alert('Testing')", True)`
 ```

  'ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "msg", "alert('Test')", True)



```
End If

End Sub `
````

```
**UPDATE** 

my Script manager is in the Master Page :

  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
         <Scripts>
             <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />
             <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" />
    </Scripts>


the text box is inside the Update panel:

      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
              <fieldset>
     <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderItem" CausesValidation="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
    </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your UpdatePanels and ScriptManagers are setup, try replacing:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(pp, pp.GetType(), "Notify", "alert('" & s & "');", True)
```

With this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "Notify", "alert('" & s & "');", True)
```

Check this post explaining the difference in detail here:

[The Difference Between Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript and Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667538/The-Difference-Between-Page-ClientScript-RegisterS)

Comment: Please check my update.. I've tried that previously and it did not work!

Comment: Is your button that is calling the event also in updatePanel1? How about this?
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanel1, updatePanel1.GetType(), "Notify", "alert('" & s & "');", True)

Comment: yes it is inside update panel .. that is not working either!!

Comment: Can you provide the full code of the page? And master page if possible.